# Как использовать свои html теги в textview?

Tags: java, android, html, textview

Например есть текст: "`<![CDATA[`Трали `<c>`вали`</c>]]>`"и вывожу я его так:

```
text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

и `Html.fromHtml`.

Естественно тег `<c></c>` не работает, а мне нужно, чтобы текст внутри него был определенного цвета например. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Можете через `Html.fromHtml` по разметке - `<font color="#fa6238">Этот текст будет другого цвета</font>`

Comment: цвет это как пример, вообще там и эффект углубления, и шрифт другой.. поэтому легче через тег один, а где-то в java это прописать все

Comment: Есть и другие работающие тэги, но если Вам их недостаточно используйте [`Html.fromHtml(source, flags, imageGetter, tagHandler)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler)) и в своей реализации интерфейса `Html.TagHandler` сами будете вставлять нужные спаны вместо тэгов.

Comment: устраивают, но какой работающий тег сможет это сделать?